# PostGIS update of Geometry from Java from Polygon object

Tags: java, jdbc, postgis

I am trying to update a PostGIs geometry column with data from an external file. The number of points in some of the polygons is over 35k and the ST_GeomFromText method does not work because the text string is too long. I can read the points into a Polygon object and I would like to do something like:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.preparedStatment("update x set y = ? where z = ?");
ps.setBinary(1, polygon);
ps.setString(2, key);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

I have not been able to find any examples on how do this. Could someone please point me toward the documentation or give an example I can follow?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, I did some testing and whipped up the following example for your benefit. I also just made it available as a [GIST on Github](https://gist.github.com/ProgrammerDan/9265521), feel free to clone and explore.

First, here's a DDL for a table I created in a new database `gis_data` which is built on the `template_postgis` database template:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sample_table
(
  "key" character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  large_poly geometry NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT simple_pl PRIMARY KEY (key)
)
```

This table is used in my Java example, listed below. Be sure to modify the `DriverManager.getConnection()` line with your credentials.

```java
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import org.postgis.*;

public class JavaGIS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.sql.Connection conn;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gis_data";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "postgres", "");

            ((org.postgresql.PGConnection)conn).addDataType("geometry",Class.forName("org.postgis.PGgeometry"));
            ((org.postgresql.PGConnection)conn).addDataType("box3d",Class.forName("org.postgis.PGbox3d"));

            Polygon geo = new Polygon(
                            new LinearRing[] {
                                new LinearRing(
                                    new Point[] {
                                        new Point(-1.0d, -1.0d,  0.5d),
                                        new Point( 1.0d, -1.0d,  0.0d),
                                        new Point( 1.0d,  1.0d, -0.5d),
                                        new Point(-1.0d,  1.0d,  0.0d),
                                        new Point(-1.0d, -1.0d,  0.5d)
                                    }
                                )
                            }
                        );
            PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO sample_table (key_value, large_poly) VALUES (?, ?)");
            s.setString(1, "poly1");
            s.setObject(2, new PGgeometry(geo));

            int rows = s.executeUpdate();

            if (rows > 0) {
                System.out.println(" Successful insert! ");
            } else {
                System.out.println(" Failed insert!");
            }
            s.close();

            Statement qs = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet r = qs.executeQuery("SELECT key_value, large_poly FROM sample_table");
            while( r.next() ) {
                /*
                * Retrieve the geometry as an object then cast it to the geometry type.
                * Print things out.
                */
                String key = r.getString(1);
                PGgeometry geom = (PGgeometry)r.getObject(2);

                if (geom.getGeoType() == Geometry.POLYGON) {
                    System.out.println("Found a polygon with key " + key);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Found a PostGIS geometry object " + geom.getGeoType() + " having key " + key);
                }
            }
            qs.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Be sure to include a [recent Postgresql jdbc driver jar](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html), and the [PostGIS jar file](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/postgis_installation.html#idp6109488) in your classpath while compiling and executing this example.

This example is largely based on the [PostGIS example](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ch05.html#id2765827) which illustrates select so beautifully and simply. Inserts are just as easy, because of the great work PostGIS has done on their extensions.

If you already have your data in a PostGIS Geometry object, just do like in my example and wrap it in a PGgeometry object for insertion into the database. That will let the database driver deal with how exactly to transmit it (likely as binary data). Once I actually followed the [instructions on how to construct Polygons](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ch04.html#OGC_Validity), everything worked quite nicely.

Disclaimer: I have only tried this with simple polygons, but the principles are sound. Let me know how it goes with the very large polygons you are dealing with!

Comment: That worked. Thanks for taking the time to put this together.

Comment: On a side note I received the error 'index row size 4096 exceeds maximum 2712 for index' and had to drop the index. I am not sure if this configurable. If not, 2712 is the max size for polygons you need to do relate selects on.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! For your side note - do you mean you had an index on the geometry database field? I'm not surprised at a limit, but might be worth investigating the PostGIS docs to see if there are hints on navigating this limit. Regardless, good luck, and thanks for the followup.

Comment: I created the spatial index wrong as it turns out. After reading the docs I added 'using GIST(column name)' to the index create and that fixed it. Thanks again.

Comment: Perfect. Have fun with PostGIS. I have fond memories, I look forward to working with it again.

Answer (score 1):

Great work.

But i need to specify SRID (4326), otherwise the database is rejecting the polygon.

any hints?

solved it with using strings.

```
String bbox ="SRID=4326;POLYGON(("+lu+","+lo+","+ro+","+ru+","+lu+"))";
pstmt.setObject(12,new PGgeometry(bbox));
```

Comment: To set the SRID programatically, first create the Geometry object itself, set it's SRID, and then wrap it in PGgeometry. Example:

`org.postgis.Polygon poly = new Polygon(/*...init code...*/);
poly.setSrid(4326);
PGgeometry geom = new PGgeometry(poly);`